# How to show chartboost ads if revmob fails to show up?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am running revmob in my app but revmob fails to appear in many countries.I want to show the chartboost ads if revmob fails to appear..

kindly help me in applying chartboost if revmob fails

Answer (score 0):

You can use ads delegates for this, for example, to show an fullscreen:

```
RevMobFullscreen *fs = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
fs.delegate = self;
[fs showAd];
```

An then call the chartboost ad in the delegate method:

```
- (void)revmobAdDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Ad failed: %@", error);
    // Code to show a chartboost ad
}
```

They have an working example that came with the SDK.